# CMake try_compile() not finding correct Windows 10 SDK

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to compile [my fork of ReactOS](https://github.com/SunburstApps/ReactOS) using CMake 3.9.0-MSVC_2 (as included with Visual Studio 2017, 15.4 update). When I have CMake generate NMake makefiles or Ninja inputs, it works just fine. However, when I tell CMake to generate a Visual Studio 2017 solution, it fails with a weird error. Here's how to reproduce this issue:

1. Clone `git@github.com:SunburstApps/ReactOS`. (It's a big repo, so please be patient. I have not been able to consistently reproduce this issue on a smaller project, in case anyone asks.)
2. In the root of the project directory, run `configure.cmd VSSolution` from a VS2017 x86 C++ tools command prompt. This will tell CMake to generate a Visual Studio solution (the exact version is inferred from the copy of cl.exe in the path).

I get the following CMake output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Investigating the `CMakeError.log` file reveals the problem is actually something else. The vcxproj file that CMake generated to identify the compiler is refusing to link, complaining that `ucrtd.lib` can't be found. If I add the following line of code to the top-level CMakeLists.txt file, it will then progress slightly further (successfully identifying the compiler), only to die of the same issue during a `try_compile()` run to "detect compiler features".

```
set(CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION 10.0.15063.0)
```

I have come to the conclusion that CMake is generating files without the Windows SDK target platform set, which is causing VS to refuse to locate `ucrtd.lib`. The `set()` line above tells CMake to add that specific version to the vcxproj files it generates, but clearly it doesn't add it to all of them.

I have tried other solutions I have found searching SO, including installing the Windows 8.1 SDK and running the CMake command as an administrator. Nothing helps. I need to generate a solution file so I can write code for this project using Visual Studio's excellent C++ editor. (I have also tried using the built-in CMake support in VS2017, but have found that it does not quite work due to ReactOS' specific cross-compiling requirements.) Can anyone give me some pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Does a hello world cmake project work from your visual studio command prompt?

Comment: It works for me in both a `x64` as well as the `x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017`. I use CMake from msys2 tho, but the generated project should also work with VS’ integrated CMake.